# Where is the key that signed neo4j-2.1.5-1.noarch.rpm?

Tags: neo4j

At http://yum.neo4j.org/ there are instructions for using the yum repo there by first installing a public key from http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key.  After installing that key, RPM shows it as installed,

```
bash$ rpm -qa gpg-pubkey'*'
gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3
gpg-pubkey-01182252-544ee144
bash$ rpm -qi `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey'*' | sed 1d` | sed /BEGIN/q
Name        : gpg-pubkey                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 01182252                          Vendor: (none)
Release     : 544ee144                      Build Date: Wed 19 Nov 2014 02:08:02 PM UTC
Install Date: Wed 19 Nov 2014 02:08:02 PM UTC      Build Host: localhost
Group       : Public Keys                   Source RPM: (none)
Size        : 0                                License: pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Summary     : gpg(Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>)
Description :
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
bash$
```

... but the RPM that yum gets won't install with signature checks
turned on.  It appears to want not key 01182252 but key 2dc499c3:

```
bash$ sudo yum install -y neo4j 2>&1 | tail
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 40 M
Installed size: 45 M
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 2dc499c3: NOKEY


Public key for neo4j-2.1.5-1.noarch.rpm is not installed
bash$
```

It's possible to ignore the key at debian.neo4j.org and instead query gnupg's default key server:

```
bash$ gpg --recv-keys 2dc499c3
gpg: requesting key 2DC499C3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: /home/vagrant/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 2DC499C3: public key "Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
bash$
```

Then after importing it into RPM's key database, yum will install neo4j:

```
bash$ gpg --export -a 2dc499c3 > ~/tmp/neo4j.asc
bash$ sudo rpm --import ~/tmp/neo4j.asc
bash$ sudo yum install -y neo4j
```

...

```
Complete!
bash$
```

Is this key the authoritative one now?

```
bash$ rpm -qi `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey* | grep 2dc499c3`
Name        : gpg-pubkey                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2dc499c3                          Vendor: (none)
Release     : 508bf4b0                      Build Date: Wed 19 Nov 2014 08:19:42 PM UTC
Install Date: Wed 19 Nov 2014 08:19:42 PM UTC      Build Host: localhost
Group       : Public Keys                   Source RPM: (none)
Size        : 0                                License: pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Summary     : gpg(Neo Technology Admins <admins@neotechnology.com>)
Description :
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: rpm-4.8.0 (NSS-3)
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=2b2E
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

bash$
```

If not, where can we get key 2dc499c3 that neo4j-2.1.5-1.noarch.rpm
was signed with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  I've re-signed all the RPM's with the key referenced in the instructions (the old one expired and broke all the Debian packages), and tested installation via `yum install neo4j` on an Amazon Linux machine.  That worked OK.

Note that our Yum/RPM support is still experimental.  We'll probably sign those RPM's with a grown-up key soon, or even rebuild the whole repo.  We also welcome feedback on how we can improve our experience on RPM platforms - thanks!

Julian.